# What's the maximum number of subnets that can be created per region in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I am using GCP as my cloud provider and I want to create a shared VPC to be used by my projects so I can have them communicate to each other using only private IP addresses. So I want to use only four regions, also I want to create a subnet for every project and maybe more than a subnet per project but I am wondering about whether there is a limit on:

1- The total number of the subnets I can create.

2- The number of subnets per region I can create.

A clear response would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend reading about VPCs in Google Cloud. I think you misunderstand what a VPC is and what subnets are and what they are used for. Each Google Cloud Project receives its own VPC which is isolated from all other VPCs. The issue you will have is the requirement to recreate some of the VPCs so that the private IP address range does not overlap with other VPCs. Unless you have a specific networking requirement, you do not need to create more than one subnet per region. A single VPC is global encompassing all regions. You do not need to limit the regions by manipulating subnets.

Comment: In most cases the purpose of multiple projects is isolation. Rethink why you want to connect isolated projects together. You may find it better to merge related services into the same project, which will often improve security, reduce costs and simplify management. Opinions vary on the best strategy. The best strategy requires more details than your post provides.

Comment: They say in the docs that the maximum number of secondary IP ranges per subnet is 30, here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_network does that mean that a max of 15 gke clusters are allowed by subnet? knowing that each cluster requires 2 secondary ranges, one for the pods and the other for the services...

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to refer to @JohnHanley's answers through the comments:

> Each Google Cloud Project receives its own VPC which is isolated from all other VPCs. The issue you will have is the requirement to recreate some of the VPCs so that the private IP address range does not overlap with other VPCs. Unless you have a specific networking requirement, you do not need to create more than one subnet per region. A single VPC is global encompassing all regions. You do not need to limit the regions by manipulating subnets.
>
> Rethink why you want to connect isolated projects together. You may find it better to merge related services into the same project, which will often improve security, reduce costs and simplify management.

Additionally, the total number of subnetwork ranges per VPC network varies per project, it will be best to check it from your Google Console by going to IAM & Admin > Quotas and use the metrics described from this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_network:%7E:text=Subnetwork%20ranges%20per%20VPC%20network)